# If I create an organization, can I limit what boards the members can see?

Tags: trello, privacy, security, permissions

I would like to create an organization for our company, with boards for each department.

I need some department boards, such as HR, available only to certain people in the organization. Can I give certain people permission to certain boards?

Furthermore, I need to be able to move cards between boards, such as HR and Training. Is this possible?

Can these two things be done?

Comment: Please separate this into two questions. Yes, you can move cards between boards by clicking the "Move" button on the back of the card.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a board within an organization private so that only members of that board would be able to see it. To do so, just add go to the board, select "Options" > "Settings" > "Permissions" and set visibility to "Members".